# How to setup Google iosched source as a reference project on Eclipes

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying use Google iosched as a reference project to learn the best practices on Android UI designing.

What are the steps that I need to follow in order setup and run the source code on Eclipse

Comment: * I downloaded iosched2011 in a .zip format file from  https://github.com/underhilllabs/iosched2011
* Created an Android project using an existing source by using the above sources
* Copied ‘android-support-v4.jar’ and ‘libGoogleAnalytics.jar’ to lib folder
I cannot generate R.java file

Comment: Make sure your new project name is used for the new package names everywhere, even in the Manifest (if you want to make things simpler for yourself, re-import everything again and use the original names for everything so nothing breaks because of that). Clean the project and change the config build path for the jars. And then do "organize imports" or Ctrl-shift-O on each file remaining with errors. Hopefully, someone else will have time to give you more detailed instructions, I do not have the time to do it right now.

Comment: @Stephan Still I can't get this project into working conditions.

Comment: Ok, which API Levels are you targeting?

Comment: It automatically selects 7. I didn't change that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ECLIPSE : File -> New -> Android Project :

Project Name "iosched" .

SELECT "Create Project From Existing Source" and specify the dir .../iosched/android

Next , Choose Android 3.2 (API LEVEL 13) then finish .

Follow the instructions to retreive the 2 jars : iosched/android/libs/README.txt and copy them to libs folder .

Right click on both jars then BUILD PATH -> Add To Build PATH .

Clean Project if necessary .

And that should do it !